# How to simulate "openmp private" in pthread

Tags: pthreads, openmp

I am using pthread in order to parallelize some code. First, I parallelized it with openmp. It was fairly easy and straightforward. Because I only made a variable private in order to avoid race condition. I want to do the same in my pthread code. What can I do?

Comment: Maybe show some code?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your code/purpose you can either use pthread mutex to serialize access to some shared resource/value so only one thread is modifying it at any time:
  - pthread_mutex_create/destroy
  - pthread_mutex_lock/unlock
  + make resource/value itself volatile to avoid compiler time optimization
or you can use thread local values:
  - pthread_key_create/delete
  - pthread_setspecific
  - pthread_getspecific
though local variable in pthread start_routine might do same thing for you.